# Why does this 8 appear in my assembler code?

Tags: assembly

This is my assembler code and when I run it A random 8 appears and I don't know how to get rid of it.

```
    B main

number  DEFW    4
verse   DEFB    " men went to mow\nWent to mow a meadow\n",0
verse2  DEFB    " men," 



    ALIGN


main    ADR R0,number   ;puts address of number into R0
        SWI 4           ;prints value in number

        ADR R0,verse    
        SWI 3           ;prints verse

        ADR R0,number
        SWI 4           ;prints value number

        ADR R0,verse2   ;places the address of verse to R0
        SWI 3           ;prints verse2

        SWI 2
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

You didn't null terminate your `verse2` like you did `verse`, so it will keep printing the text until it finds a 0 byte.

The 8 is likely part of the first instruction, which would probably start as `0x38 0x00 ...`, 0x38 being the ASCII code for '8'.

Not sure what `SWI 3` does in case of nonprintables, but maybe there is memory in the 1-31 range values anywhere inbetwen, and is getting ignored.